# AJAX POST problem, variables empty, but showing in echo

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Ajax post sending 2 date variables that server receiving but for some reason cannot work with them like they are empty. gettype function return NULL but in echo they show correctly.

Checked js variables before sending - they correct, also Network log showing right request params. It means my ajax post request for some reason not correctly receiving?  I've send dates with exact same  post parameters with Postman and server return correct file.

- [Netwotk log + console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hbya.png)
- [POSTMAN params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DswZ.png)

file export.php

```
<?php
$host       = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "";
$dbname     = "test";
$dsn        = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname";
$options    = array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
              ); 
require '../PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require '../PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php';
$date1 = $_POST["start"];
$date2 = $_POST["end"];
//echo $date1;
 try  {
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT OrderDate, OrderPrice, Adress, Delivery FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate <='$date2' AND OrderDate >='$date1'");
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();
  } catch(PDOException $error) {
      echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
  };
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$row = 1;
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row, 'OrderDate')
                              ->setCellValue('B'.$row, 'OrderPrice')
                              ->setCellValue('C'.$row, 'Adress')
                              ->setCellValue('D'.$row, 'Delivery');
$row++;
while ($rec = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row, $rec['OrderDate'])
                                  ->setCellValue('B'.$row, $rec['OrderPrice'])
                                  ->setCellValue('C'.$row, $rec['Adress'])
                                  ->setCellValue('D'.$row, $rec['Delivery']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$row)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_XLSX15);
    $row++;
};
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
  header("Content-type: " . $mimeType);
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xlsx"');
   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
   $objWriter->save('php://output');
?>
```

file create.php

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
   <div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: fit-content">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();
    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }
    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);
    cb(start, end);
});
</script>
<br>
<form id="form1" method="post" action="../public/export.php">
  <button type="submit">Export</button>
    <script>
     $("#form1").submit(function s() {
    let start = $('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    let end = $('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log(start,end);
    $.post({
  url: '../public/export.php',
  data: { start: start,end: end },
  success: function() {/* //another way for receive file
    fetch('http://localhost/1/public/export.php')
  .then(resp => resp.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.style.display = 'none';
    a.href = url;
    a.download = $('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '.xlsx';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  })
  .catch(() => alert('error'));*/
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
     alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
  }
});
});
    </script>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! If you can echo the variables and verify that they're there, then the issue is not that the server isn't receiving them. It's probably something else, like your SQL or something.

Comment: sql should be right, since when i send postman request it works

Answer (score 0):

please remove contentType

```
 $.post({
   url: '../public/export.php',
   data: { start: start,end: end },
   success: function() {
   }
  });
```

Comment: removed but still same problem